# How to call gridview from a shared function

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a routine that i call clientside using Javascript. For this reason, it has to be a webmethod hence it must be 'shared' (static in C#)

```
<System.Web.Services.WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Sub LoadBewerkIndirecteKosten(_team As String, _year As Integer)
    Try
        '    dconnection = DatabaseConnection.Instance
        Dim con As New Connection

        Dim sql As String = ""
        sql = String.Format(" exec CSSSR_FEZ_Get_BewerkIndirecteKosten '{0}', {1} ", _team, _year)
        Dim dt As DataTable ' = New DataTable
        Dim ds As DataSet = con.QueryUnsecure(sql, Nothing, EDLQueryOptions.DataSet)

        dt = ds.Tables(0)
        SSR_IndirecteKosten.gvBewerkIndirecteKosten.DataSource = dt
        gvBewerkIndirecteKosten.DataBind()
    Catch ex As Exception
        log.Fatal(String.Format("Error in: {0}: {1}", "LoadBewerkIndirecteKosten", ex.Message))
    End Try
End Sub
```

In the javascript (which is in my aspx), i call this function like this:

```
PageMethods.LoadBewerkIndirecteKosten('FEZ', 2014, OnSucceeded, OnFailed);
```

Normally this construction works perfectly, as long is a don't call sreen components, but in this case, i run a stored procedure, fill a datatable and want to databind it to the gridview.

Does anyone know how?? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: what about passing value from javscript to asp:hidden field and trigger postbacko in updatpanel ?

Comment: Yes, that is the other way to call codebehind functions from javascript, but i just like the pagemethod way more, because it involves far less code.

Comment: don't agree about less code :) because the alternative is to return DataTable as json from WebMethod and populate the grid from javascript  yourself or using a jQuery plugin like Datatable http://www.datatables.net/